# Catching Errors Inside Promises and Rejecting Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I have written a function that returns a promise to read a file line by line asynchronously but the problem is that if the file doesn't exist an error is thrown and the application crashes. I have surrounded the code in a try catch block but the code execution never goes into the catch block but terminates.

Secondly can I reject a promise and then return a json object from the promise?

Like `reject({success: false});`

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

class fileParser{
    readPolicyFile = function(filePath, fileName) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                let response = {};
                let readInterface = readline.createInterface({
                    input: fs.createReadStream(`${filePath}/${fileName}`),
                    terminal: false
                });
    
                readInterface
                    .on('line', line => {
                        // Do processing here to create the response
                    })
                    .on('close', () => {
                        resolve(response);
                    });
            } catch(err){
                console.log("Inside catach block");
                reject(err);
            }
        })
    }
}


module.exports = new fileParser();
```

[image: Error]

Comment: You need to handle the `error` event on that stream. Not wrap the code in `try`/`catch`

Comment: Thanks @Bergi and @evolutionxbox, I was actually handling it in readInterface but it needs to be handled in the `fs` readstream. This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will never see `Inside catach block` line,
because `createReadStream` will not throw an error as "normal".
It will emit `error` event when it want to throw an error.

What you need is handle `error` of `createReadStream` (not of `readInterface`)

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

class fileParser {
  readPolicyFile = function (filePath, fileName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let response = {};

      // create a stream and handle it's error event
      const stream = fs.createReadStream(`${filePath}/${fileName}`);
      stream.on('error', (error) => {
        reject(error);
        // or reject({success: false}), but why call reject with data
        // If you don't want to handle error of readPolicyFile function, just call resolve({success: false})
      });

      let readInterface = readline.createInterface({
        input: stream,
        terminal: false
      });

      readInterface
        .on('line', line => {
          // Do processing here to create the response
        })
        .on('close', () => {
          resolve(response);
        });
    })
  }
}

module.exports = new fileParser();
```

Comment: Thanks @hoangdv that is a good point I don't need to reject the promise as I don't want to handle the error and just return error response.